# antrl-hibernate maven dependency not found

Tags: hibernate, maven, antlr

I try to add hibernate dependency to my POM file, but I have problems with antlr version 2.7.7.

I put this in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The error I get is

```
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository
```

I try to exclude it by using

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
     <groupId>antlr</groupId>
     <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

, but I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:LEntityManager
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... it's pretty weird. Try once more but add `-U` switch to Maven command. It should help, but I still don't see a reason for this weird message. That could happen for artifacts that just appeared in Maven Central and you have to wait few hours since that's your local cache expiration time, but this `antlr` version is from 2007!

Comment: I am using eclipse and from there I can update the dependencies. What should I do to add the -U option

Comment: You should check `Update Snapshots` in your launch' configuration.